# Pass props from parent to child using a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prop

I am working on an app in which the user have to select from four dropdowns and once the user clicks ok button I want to send all the selection to a child component to create a chart. I had it working without the button click as I was passing the selection as a prop and making the computation in the child component like thid

`<ChildComponent  :name="name" :email="email" :date="date" ></ChildComponent>`

Now I  need to have a button that when clicked will do the same and update the props and send them to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You would just create a method that updates the value of the props that you are passing into the child

```js
<script setup>
const name = ref('')
const email = ref('')
const date = ref('')

function handleUpdate() {
  name.value = /* ... */
  email.value = /* ... */
  date.value = /* ... */
}
</script>

<template>
  <ChildComponent :name="name" :email="email" :date="date" />
  <button @click="handleUpdate">OK</button>
</template>
```

It's a bit hard to see what you mean but are you sure you can't use a form here to group the values together if you have 4 selects?

Comment: I don't really know how form would work , and the button is on the parent component not the child which is where I have a confusion. Also each select can be changed individually so I am not sure if form would work

Comment: I just wrote it out, all you values are indeed in the parent component in my example. When you click the ok button in the parent the values would be changed reactively and that updates the child component accordingly

Comment: Thank you but I guess I am doing many computation on the props it started to give me error so I found another way not to load the child unless the button is clicked the problem is when it is clicked I set a flag to true and now the props can be changed without the clicked button. Where should i reset the flag to false after everything is loaded?